# Iterating through string array that is being passed as a parameter - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, iteration

I am writing a static page that displays information from a json format, but cannot iterate through string arrays after passing the json as a parameter.

My goal is to show each "responsibility" and "qualification" from the json format. I've tried using .map() and .forEach() on the part of the object `props` that has the array of "responsibility" and "qualification" but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the json

```
Example JSON object:

en: {
    "job-1": {
      location: "123 main street",
      title: "Awesome Person #2",
      summary: "Cool beans",
      responsibilities:
        ["responsibility 1", "responsibility 2", "responsibility 3"],
      qualifications: ["Qualification 1", "Qualification 2", "Qualification 3"]
    },
    "job-2": {
      location: "",
      title: "",
      summary: "",
      responsibilities: [""],
      qualifications: [""]
    },
    },
    "job-2": {
      location: "",
      title: "",
      summary: "",
      responsibilities: [""],
      qualifications: [""]
    },
},
fr:{...},
it:{...},
```

App.js

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="o-app">
      <JobList jobs={jobs.en} />
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

JobList.js

```
function JobList(props) {
  
    return (
      <div className="c-job-list">
        <div className="o-wrap">
          <h2 className='list-title'>Open Positions</h2>
          <ul>
            { 
              Object.keys(props.jobs).map(key => <Job key={key} details={props.jobs[key]} />)
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  
}

export default JobList
```

And Jobs.js

```
function Job(props) {

  const { getCollapseProps, getToggleProps, isExpanded } = useCollapse();

  Array.prototype.map.call(arrayRespon, child => {
    <li>
      {child}
    </li>
  })

  return (
    <li className={'c-job-item c-job-item--permenant'} {...getToggleProps()}>
      <h3 className="c-job-item__title">{props.details.title}</h3>
      <p {...getCollapseProps()} className="c-job-item__summ">{props.details.summary}</p>
      <br />
      <ul {...getCollapseProps()} className="c-job-item__summ">{props.details.responsibilities}</ul>
     

      <p {...getCollapseProps()} className="c-job-item__summ">{props.details.qualifications}</p>

    </li>
  )
}




export default Job
```

Answer (score 0):

Classic case of answer the question, find the solution as I'm waiting for a response.

For anyone curious or in the same shoes as me years from now, the solution was to do

```
{Object.keys(props.details.responsibilities).map(key => <li>{key}:{props.details.responsibilities[key]}</li>)}
```

inside of Job.js

Much like how I did it in JobList.js, I just didn't think the same could be done for an array within the json.

:)